# how to preserve control type between postbacks in asp.net webforms

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to create a simple form generating engine in webforms and I am having trouble with maintaining the controls on page during postbacks.The user can select the type of the control form a `DropDownList` and if it is a radio button (which is in index 3), it will enable a `TextBox` which defines the `GroupName` property of the radio button.I have set a `SelectedIndexChanged` to handle the disabling and enabling of the `txtboxGroupName`.

for every control that the user adds, I want to show them a preview of what has happened so far in the form.The preview happens in a `Panel` control with the id of `panel`.

The problem is that in postbacks, the created controls disappear form the panel (which is the way it should be with asp.net postback system) and I want to preserve them.Since I don't know the control's type, I can't just put some ids in the viewstate for example to preseve the controls with those ids

I tried to do something like this but it is not working :

this is the code behind:

```
    public int NumberOfControls
    {
        get { return (int)ViewState["NumOfControls"]; }
        set { ViewState["NumOfControls"] = value; }
    }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
            this.NumberOfControls = 0;
        else
            this.CreateControls();
    }

    private void CreateControls()
    {
        for (int counter = 0; counter < this.NumberOfControls; counter++)
        {
            Control temp = new Control();
            temp.ID = "control_id_" + counter.ToString();
            panel.Controls.Add(temp);
        }
    }
    protected void ddlControlType_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        switch (ddlControlType.SelectedIndex)
        {
            case 0:
            case 2:
                txtboxText.Enabled = true;
                txtboxGroupName.Enabled = false;
                break;
            case 1:
                txtboxText.Enabled = false;
                txtboxGroupName.Enabled = false;
                break;
            case 3:
                txtboxText.Enabled = true;
                txtboxGroupName.Enabled = true;
                break;
        }
    }
    protected void btnAddControl_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Control tempControl = null;
        switch (ddlControlType.SelectedIndex)
        {
            case 0:
                tempControl = new Label();
                ((Label)tempControl).Text = txtboxText.Text;
                break;
            case 1:
                tempControl = new TextBox();
                break;
            case 2:
                tempControl = new CheckBox();
                ((CheckBox)tempControl).Text = txtboxText.Text;
                break;
            case 3:
                tempControl = new RadioButton();
                ((RadioButton)tempControl).Text = txtboxText.Text;
                ((RadioButton)tempControl).GroupName = txtboxGroupName.Text;
                break;
        }
        tempControl.ID = "control_id_" + this.NumberOfControls.ToString();
        panel.Controls.Add(tempControl);
        this.NumberOfControls++;
    }
```

this is my aspx page

```
<div class="main-wrapper">
    <form dir="rtl" id="form" runat="server">
        <label>Desired Control : </label>
        <asp:DropDownList AutoPostBack="true" ID="ddlControlType" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlControlType_SelectedIndexChanged" runat="server">
            <asp:ListItem Text="label"></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Text="text box"></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Text="check box"></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Text="radio button"></asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>
        <br /><br />
        <label class="label">control's text : </label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtboxText" runat="server" CssClass="txtbox"></asp:TextBox>
        <label class="label">group name (only for radio button)</label>
        <asp:TextBox Enabled="false" ID="txtboxGroupName" runat="server" CssClass="txtbox"></asp:TextBox>
        <br /><br />
        <asp:Button ID="btnAddControl" CssClass="btn" Text="add to form" OnClick="btnAddControl_Click" runat="server" />
        <hr />
        <h1>form preview</h1>
        <asp:Panel ID="panel" runat="server">
        </asp:Panel>
    </form>
</div>
```

the `btnAddControl` is the button that triggers the addition of a control.The control that this method creates, won't be preserved in the postbacks(whether it is another button click or changing of the dropdownlist's selected index)

the problem with this code is that nothing is being added in the panel control (I think it is because I used a generic `Control` type, but again, I don't know the type)

how can I preserve these controls?

**UPDATE:**

I recreated my code to this one but it still won't work:

```
    public Dictionary<string, Type> ControlTypes
    {
        get { return (Dictionary<string, Type>)Session["ControlTypes"]; }
        set { Session["ControlTypes"] = value; }
    }
    public int NumberOfControls
    {
        get { return (int)ViewState["NumOfControls"]; }
        set { ViewState["NumOfControls"] = value; }
    }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            this.NumberOfControls = 0;
            ControlTypes = new Dictionary<string, Type>();
        }
        else
            this.CreateControls();
    }

    private void CreateControls()
    {
        for (int counter = 0; counter < this.NumberOfControls; counter++)
        {
            string controlId = "control_id_" + counter.ToString();
            Type controlType = ControlTypes[controlId];
            ProperyInfo[] properties = controlType.GetProperties();
            Object controlObject = Activator.CreateInstance(controlType);
            foreach (var propery in properties)
            {
                If (propery.Name == "ID")
                    Property.SetValue(controlObject, controlId, null);
            }
            panel.Controls.Add(controlObject as Control)
        }
    }

    protected void ddlControlType_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        switch (ddlControlType.SelectedIndex)
        {
            case 0:
            case 2:
                txtboxText.Enabled = true;
                txtboxGroupName.Enabled = false;
                break;
            case 1:
                txtboxText.Enabled = false;
                txtboxGroupName.Enabled = false;
                break;
            case 3:
                txtboxText.Enabled = true;
                txtboxGroupName.Enabled = true;
                break;
        }
    }

    protected void btnAddControl_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Control tempControl = null;
        switch (ddlControlType.SelectedIndex)
        {
            case 0:
                tempControl = new Label();
                ((Label)tempControl).Text = txtboxText.Text;
                break;
            case 1:
                tempControl = new TextBox();
                break;
            case 2:
                tempControl = new CheckBox();
                ((CheckBox)tempControl).Text = txtboxText.Text;
                break;
            case 3:
                tempControl = new RadioButton();
                ((RadioButton)tempControl).Text = txtboxText.Text;
                ((RadioButton)tempControl).GroupName = txtboxGroupName.Text;
                break;
        }
        string controlId = "control_id_" + this.NumberOfControls.ToString();
        tempControl.ID = controlId;
        panel.Controls.Add(tempControl);
        this.NumberOfControls++;
        ControlTypes.Add(controlId, tempControl.GetType());
    }
```

This code actually adds the controls on page load, but even with the same ids, the viewstate seems to ignore the controls' state and won't fill its properties
What should I do now?

Comment: i not sure why you need `else
            this.CreateControls();
    }`?

Comment: if it is a postback then I should create the controls in page load again, I am sure about this part.The part I have a problem in is the CreateControl itself and what goes in it

Comment: code, that you provide, is code for web control? or web page? can you provide _complex sample_?

Comment: it is the code behind of the webpage
this is the exact code I am working with

Comment: provide also aspx markup

Comment: thanks for your help, I added them

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95218/discussion-between-grundy-and-user2078785).

Answer (score 0):

I recommend use data-binding to achieve "dynamic" controls. Also it is great idea to separate "data model" from actual controls. See example below.

Markup:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptControls" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="rptControls_ItemDataBound" >
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label runat="server" Visible="false" ID="lbl" />
        <asp:CheckBox runat="server" Visible="false" ID="chx" />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtText" runat="server" />
<asp:Button ID="btnAddLabel" runat="server" OnClick="btnAddLabel_Click" Text="Add label" />
<asp:Button ID="btnAddCheckBox" runat="server"  OnClick="btnAddCheckBox_Click" Text="Add check box" />
```

Data model:

```
[Serializable]
public abstract class ControlDescriptor {
  public abstract void SetupControl(ControlCollection controls);

}
[Serializable]
public class LabelDescriptor : ControlDescriptor {
  public string Text { get; set; }
  public override void SetupControl(ControlCollection controls) {
    var cotrol = controls.OfType<Label>().First(c => c.ID == "lbl");
    cotrol.Visible = true;
    cotrol.Text = Text;
  }
}
[Serializable]
public class CheckBoxDescriptor : ControlDescriptor {
  public string Text { get; set; }
  public override void SetupControl(ControlCollection controls) {
    var cotrol = controls.OfType<CheckBox>().First(c => c.ID == "chx");
    cotrol.Visible = true;
    cotrol.Text = Text;
  }
}
```

Code behind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  Rebind();
}

protected IList<ControlDescriptor> Descriptors {
  get {
    var result = (IList<ControlDescriptor>)ViewState["Descriptors"];
    if (result == null) {
      result = new List<ControlDescriptor>();
      ViewState["Descriptors"] = result;
    }
    return result;
  }
}

protected void Rebind() {
  rptControls.DataSource = Descriptors;
  rptControls.DataBind();
}

protected void btnAddCheckBox_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  Descriptors.Add(new CheckBoxDescriptor { Text = txtText.Text });
  Rebind();
}

protected void btnAddLabel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  Descriptors.Add(new LabelDescriptor { Text = txtText.Text });
  Rebind();
}

protected void rptControls_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e) {
  if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item ||
    e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem) {
    var descriptor = (ControlDescriptor)e.Item.DataItem;
    descriptor.SetupControl(e.Item.Controls);
  }
}
```

Comment: Nice piece of code, but i want to actually generate the controls rather than making them visible and not visible